# What should be the html tag design to create table structure in mail body

Tags: c#

How will I create a mail body for the below result , I'm looking for design of html design for table:

[image]

above is the table structure i have tried but its not proper:

```
reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
while (reader.Read())
{
    mailbody +=
        "<tr>" +
        "<td>" + reader["DevName"].ToString() + "</td>" +
        "<td>" + reader["DevId"].ToString() + "</td>" +
        "<td>" + reader["LocationID"].ToString() + "</td>" +
        //"<td>" + reader["LocationName"].ToString() + "</td>" +
        "<td>" + reader["SubLocationID"].ToString() + "</td>" +
        "<td>" + reader["IPV6"].ToString() + "</td>" +
        "<td>" + reader["LastConnTime"].ToString() + "</td>" +
        "<td>" + reader["LastDisconnTime"].ToString() + "</td>" +
        "<td>" + reader["Online"].ToString() + "</td>" +
        "<td>" + reader["HardwareSerialNumber"].ToString() + "</td>" +
        "<td>" + reader["ServiceProviderID"].ToString() + "</td>" +
        "<td>" + reader["DateLastModified"].ToString() + "</td>" +
        "<tr>";
}
if (mailbody !=string.Empty)
{
    mailbody += "</table>";
    string bodyStructure = "<html><head></head><body>" + @"<table border =""1"" cellpadding=""2"" style=""border=collapse:collapse;""><tr style=""color:white; background-color:SkyBlue; font-wieght:bold;"">" + "<td>DeviceName</td> <td>DeviceID</td>  <td>LocationID</td> <td>LocationName</td>   <td>SubLocationID</td>  <td>IPAddress</td>  <td>LastConnected</td>  <td>LastDisconnected</td> <td>HardwareSerialNumber</td>  <td>DeviceStatus</td> <td>HardwareSerialNumber</td>  <td>ServiceProviderID</td>  <td>LastTransactionSync</td>" + "</tr>" + mailbody + "</body</html>";
    //message.IsBodyHtml = true;
    message.Subject = "DeleteDuplicateDevicesReport";
    message.Body = bodyStructure;
    smtp.Send(message);
}
```

Comment: It is important that mail headers contain `Content-type: text/html`

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for something along the lines of this:

```
string bodyStructure = 
    string.Format("<html><head></head><body><table border ='1' cellpadding='2' style='border=collapse:collapse;'>" +
    "<tr style='color:white; background-color:SkyBlue; font-weight:bold;'><td>DeviceName</td><td>DeviceID</td>" +
    "<td>LocationID</td><td>LocationName</td><td>SubLocationID</td><td>IPAddress</td><td>LastConnected</td>" + 
    "<td>LastDisconnected</td><td>HardwareSerialNumber</td><td>DeviceStatus</td><td>HardwareSerialNumber</td>" +
    "<td>ServiceProviderID</td> <td>LastTransactionSync</td></tr>{0}</table></body></html>",mailbody);
```

This isn't the nicest to look at, but judging by your [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54516368/what-should-be-the-html-tag-design-to-create-table-structure-in-mail-body#comment95835864_54516368), it's what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what the need is here, but this may be something close to a project I have done in the past where I needed to be able to create an HTML formatted email that included a table of dynamic number of rows of data. The way that I did that was write 2 HTML files that included place holders for the data, the first was the main html document including the table setup, the second had only the table rows `<td>` also with placeholders for the data. Then you are able to load the string from that file and use string interpolation to generate the actual HTML string. This keeps you from having a messy concatenated html string and makes future edits much simpler.